# Bind XAML TreeView MaxHeight to Containers Height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I have the problem that i want to bind the max-height of my TreeView to the height of my UserControl but the binding doesn't work.

I tried the following

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel Name="Container"> 
         <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
         <TreeView MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=Container,Path=ActualHeight}"></TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I would expect, that if I resize my window, the UserControl resizes and so the TreeView is resized too, so that if the window is to small, the TreeView-scrollbars appear.
But what I get is no scrollbars and the content of the TreeView reaches outside the window and isn't visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ridiculously common mistake. The `StackPanel` does *not* feature any resizing capabilities and should only be used for the most basic layout purposes. Instead, use a `Grid Panel` which will automatically resize its children controls:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid> 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay and helpful answer. I solved the problem with the Grid element. One small advice: the "Grid.Column" definition in your post has to be "Grid.Row" but than it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the notification, @bestfansdynamo... I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
     <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Header</TextBlock>
     <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=Container,Path=ActualHeight}"></TreeView>   
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: A `DockPanel` is fairly heavy weight control and should only be used when it's exact functionality is required. A `Grid` is far more lightweight and so is preferable in this case.